# How to execute two functions synchronously : jQuery show & animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I execute the two functions synchronously (at the same time)?
Is it possible to run the .animate function in .show function?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#tricksImg').click(function() {
    jQuery('#appear').show(function() {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: jQuery("#appear").offset().top
        });
    });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean to execute them asynchronous? Synchronously means one after each other.

Comment: "at the same time" is *concurrently* or *in parallel*. Maybe *synchronized*.

Comment: Just don't use that callback (but start `animate` immediately after starting `show`) and you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions should already execute as fast as possible, thus the callback on `animate` is useless in this case.

```
jQuery('#tricksImg').click(function() {
    jQuery('#appear').show();

    jQuery('html, body').animate({

         scrollTop: jQuery("#appear").offset().top

    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I mean asynchronous. In parallel. 
I got this to work, thank you, this logic also makes more sense.

```
jQuery('#tricksImg').click(function() {
    jQuery('#appear').show(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: jQuery("#appear").offset().top
    });
});
});
```